# constexpr static data member without initializer

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, language-lawyer

```
#include <complex>

struct S
{
  static std::complex<double> constexpr c;
};
```

gcc generates an error because an initializer is missing. Clang and MSVC do not generate an error.

As far as I know a constexpr static data member must have an initializer, even if it is of class type that has a constructor that can be called without arguments (as in this case). Unfortunately I don't have the latest C++ standard to back up my assumption.

So the correct code should initialize with a constructor, for instance:

```
struct S
{
  static std::complex<double> constexpr c {};
};
```

Can anyone prove which compiler is right and which is wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GCC is wrong.

GCC uses the C++14 rules for `constexpr` variables, which requires an initializer to be provided. This is changed per [P0386](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0386r2.pdf) (bold text is newly added text):

> *In 9.2.3.2p3, change:*
>
> If a non­-volatile **n​on-­inline** ​const static data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class definition can specify a b​*race­-or-­equal-­initializer​* in which every *initializer-­clause​* that is an ​*assignment-­expression​* is a constant expression (5.20). <del>A​ static data member of literal type can be declared in the class definition with the constexpr specifier; if so, its declaration shall specify a brace­-or-­equal-initializer in which every initializer-­clause that is an assignment­-expression is a constant expression. [ Note: In both these cases, the member may appear in constant expressions. — end note ]​</del> The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is odr-­used (3.2) in the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an initializer.​ **A​n inline static data member can be defined in the class definition and may specify a *b​race­-or-­equal­-initializer*.​ If the member is declared with the constexpr specifier, it may be redeclared in namespace scope with no initializer (this usage is deprecated; see D.X). Declarations of other static data members shall not specify a *b​race­-or-­equal-initializer*.​**

Comment: I think you are right. Clang 6.0.0 does not report an error in C++17 mode, but it does in C++14 mode and complains about a missing initializer for a constexpr static data member. So the rule seems to have changed from C++14 to C++17 (just as you have explained). gcc is wrong, and clang and MSVC (hard to believe) are right.
Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Actually it depends on the standard. The OP didn't specify a particular version of C++, therefore gcc isn't neccessarily wrong - it depends on the language version (and compiler perhaps - maybe they fixed it in the meanwhile? I don't have the latest gcc version installed).

Comment: Has a bug been filed in GCC for this?

Answer (score 7):

*In this particular case*, there are two answers:

- For C++14, gcc is **right** (i.e. constexpr static data member must have an initializer).
- For C++17 and beyond, gcc is **wrong**, since it refuses to compile conformant code.

***Former case***: In draft [N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) (C++**14**), 9.4.2.3 (Static data members) [class.static.data] (emphasis mine):

> A `static` data member of **literal type** can be declared in the class
>   definition with the `constexpr` specifier; if so, **its declaration shall
>   specify a *brace-or-equal-initializer*** in which every *initializer-clause*
>   that is an *assignment-expression* is a constant expression.

See also: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Constant_static_members.

I said "in this *particular* case", because `std::complex` [has a specialization for `double`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) that is a `LiteralType`. Therefore above rule applies.
For general (i.e. non-literal) types, see [codekaizers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50638400/1753435).

***Latter case***: For C++**17**, see [xskxzr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50639754/1753435).

Comment: is `c` a [literal](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.literal)? if not, then that doesn't apply.

Comment: For specialization of `double`, [`std::complex` is](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex).

Comment: @codekaizer Wrong paragraph. You want [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.types#def:literal_type).

Comment: @andreee You are right for C++11/14. But in C++17 the rule has changed (see the answer from xskxzr). In C++11/14 mode clang generates an error, too.

Comment: @xy: Thanks for noting, updated! Please note that you didn't specify a specific language version, so there are two different answers (as you pointed out).

Comment: @andreee Yes, I forgot to specify C++17 in my original post. Sorry for the confusion...

Answer (score 3):

From [dcl.constexpr#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.constexpr#1):

> A function or `static` data member declared with the `constexpr` specifier
>   is implicitly an `inline` function or variable

`constexpr` `static` data members  are implicitly `inline`.

Also from [class#static.data-3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class#static.data-3), **emphasis** mine:

> `inline` `static` data member may be
>   defined in the `class` definition and **may** specify a
>   `brace-or-equal-initializer`.

Thus, GCC is wrong. `brace-or-equal-initializer` is **not** *strictly required*.

Reference: [N4659](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/) C++17 Draft

Comment: is there a GCC bug for this? Any details of "may specify". To me, "may specify" means that it _may not_, case in which the constexpr no-arg c-tor for that literal type does its job. But this doesn't work and GCC mandates an initialiser