# No initializer present for constexpr static data member

Tags: static, c++17, constexpr, literals, initializer

As far as I read the following code is C++17 compliant, and indeed clang > 5.0 accepts it, but not gcc 8.2.

```
#include <type_traits> // for is_literal_type_v

struct Wrapper
{
    constexpr Wrapper() :
        initialised_(false),
        value_(0)
    {
    }
    constexpr Wrapper(int value) :
        initialised_(true),
        value_(value)
    {
    }
    const bool initialised_;
    const int value_;
};

static_assert(std::is_literal_type_v<Wrapper>, "must be a literal type");


struct Container
{
    static constexpr Wrapper w; // error: 'constexpr' static data member 'w' must have an initializer
};


int main()
{
}
```

This is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50638053/constexpr-static-data-member-without-initializer), but on top of that **I'd like to ask if there is any way (other than, well, providing an initializer) to make it work**. What I'd like to achieve is to have the no-arg c-tor of `Wrapper` called in this case (of course).

Additionally, it would be good to identify the GCC bug if there is one.

---

**Edit**: To note, my current workaround is to use namespace instead of struct. At namespace scope the `constexpr` doesn't require an initializer, it seems. But this reduces flexibility of something I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Use list initialization syntax (curly braces):

```
struct Container
{
    static constexpr Wrapper w{};
};
```

Comment: sure, but this is not a workaround for me as I need something to work in a very generic context (a macro to be precise), where passed items might or might not have initialisers

Comment: A more complete example of what you're trying to do would be useful.